# How to select WooCommerce products by post_meta and order them

Tags: php, loop, woocommerce-offtopic, mysql

I'm using the following code to select products with the following post_metas:

_product_new, _product_almost_new, _product_old

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'custom_vtp_shop_order' );

function custom_vtp_shop_order($q){
    if ( ! $q->is_main_query() ) return;
    if (! is_admin() && (is_shop() || is_archive) ) {

        $q->set( 'tax_query', array(array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( 'Sold', 'Service' ),  
            'operator' => 'NOT IN'
        )));

        $q->set('meta_query', array(array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
                'product_new' => array(
                    'key' => '_product_new',
                    'value' => '1',
                ),
                'product_almost_new' => array(
                    'key' => '_product_almost_new',
                    'value' => '1',
                ), 
                'product_old' => array(
                    'key' => '_product_old',
                    'value' => '1',
                )
            )));

        /*THIS HAS NO EFFECT*/
        $q->set('orderby', array(array( 
                'product_new' => 'DESC',
                'product_old' => 'DESC',
                'product_almost_new' => 'DESC',
            )        
        ));

    }

}
```

I want the products to then be displayed in the following order:

1. product_new
2. product_old
3. product_almost_new

I am using $q->set('orderby', array(......) but this is having no effect. My products are ALWAYS being ordered product_old, product_almost_new, product_new.

Any ideas why my 'orderby' is not working? Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `WP_Query` it's only possible to sort by a single meta value by setting the `meta_key` argument to which key you want to be able to sort by, and `orderby` to `meta_value` (or `meta_value_num` if the value is to be sorted numerically).

This is what the arguments would look like:

```
$args = array(
    'meta_key' => '_product_new',
    'orderby'  => 'meta_value_num',
    'meta_query' = array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key'   => '_product_new',
            'value' => '1',
        ),
        array(
            'key'   => '_product_almost_new',
            'value' => '1',
        ), 
        array(
            'key'   => '_product_old',
            'value' => '1',
        )
    )
);
```

That will query all posts that have `_product_new`, `_product_almost_new`, or `_product_old`, and order them so that the ones with `_product_new` will be at the top or bottom (depending on `order`).

The problem is that this will only sort by one meta value, `_product_new`, and ignore the others. But this is just a limitation of `WP_Query`. *It's not possible to sort results by multiple meta values.*

A potential solution is to have a single meta key, say `_product_age`, and set it to a numerical value that represents each of the states you want to sort by. So instead of having `_product_new` as a boolean, set `_product_age` to `1`, instead of `_product_almost_new`, set `_product_age` to `3`, and instead of `_product_old`, set `_product_age` to `2`.

Then you could use these args to sort the way you want;

```
$args = array(
    'meta_key' => '_product_age',
    'orderby'  => 'meta_value_num',
    'order'    => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' = array(
        array(
            'key'     => '_product_age',
            'value'   => array( 1, 2, 3 ),
            'compare' => 'IN',
        ),
    )
);
```

Comment: Thanks Jacob, but what about this? https://make.wordpress.org/core/2014/08/29/a-more-powerful-order-by-in-wordpress-4-0/

Comment: That means you can order by multiple of the [valid orderby parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters), but individual meta keys are not valid order parameters. You can order by `meta_value` *and* `post_title`, or `meta_value` *and* `post_date`, but you can't order by multiple `meta_value` for different keys.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but here is the possible solution:

```
$q->set('orderby', 'product_new product_old product_almost_new');
$q->set('order', 'DESC');
```

So just try to pass parameters as a string in required order.